# Model API response that contains multiple json responses

Tags: swift

Normally if I had a JSON I could model it using something like a [json formatter](https://jsonformatter.org/json-to-swift), but this would involve getting in the response a straight json, or an array and a json inside. But this is the response I get on an endpoint I need to fetch:

```
event: balance
data: {"appId":"vesper","network":"ethereum","addresses":["0x388c818ca8b9251b393131c08a736a67ccb19297"],"balance":{"deposits":{},"debt":{},"vesting":{},"wallet":{},"claimable":{},"locked":{},"nft":{}},"totals":[],"errors":[],"app":{"appId":"vesper","network":"ethereum","data":[],"displayProps":{"appName":"Vesper","images":["https://storage.googleapis.com/zapper-fi-assets/apps/vesper.png"]},"meta":{"total":0}}}

event: balance
data: {"appId":"tokens","network":"ethereum","addresses":["0x388c818ca8b9251b393131c08a736a67ccb19297"],"balance":{"deposits":{},"debt":{},"vesting":{},"wallet":{"2616394601":{"key":"2616394601","appId":"tokens","address":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","network":"ethereum","balanceUSD":153782.01257656515,"metaType":"supplied","displayProps":{"label":"ETH","secondaryLabel":null,"tertiaryLabel":null,"images":["https://storage.googleapis.com/zapper-fi-assets/tokens/ethereum/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000.png"],"stats":[],"info":[{"label":{"type":"string","value":"App"},"value":{"type":"string","value":"Tokens"}}],"balanceDisplayMode":"default"},"type":"token","contractType":"app-token","context":{"symbol":"ETH","balance":113.28575406938285,"decimals":18,"balanceRaw":"113285754069382835115","price":1357.47},"breakdown":[]}},"claimable":{},"locked":{},"nft":{}},"totals":[{"key":"2616394601","type":"app-token","network":"ethereum","balanceUSD":153782.01257656515}],"errors":[]}
```

How would I model that? I'm not asking to construct the model for me, I just want to have an idea of how to do it with such response, if I had a json response only like:

```
{"appId":"vesper","network":"ethereum","addresses":["0x388c818ca8b9251b393131c08a736a67ccb19297"],"balance":{"deposits":{},"debt":{},"vesting":{},"wallet":{},"claimable":{},"locked":{},"nft":{}},"totals":[],"errors":[],"app":{"appId":"vesper","network":"ethereum","data":[],"displayProps":{"appName":"Vesper","images":["https://storage.googleapis.com/zapper-fi-assets/apps/vesper.png"]},"meta":{"total":0}}}
```

it would be easy to model, but I get it like the first example above, with multiple events and data.

Comment: can you show us exactly what you get from your server. For example, is what you show a String ,or some object? Show how you `print` this response.

Comment: The only real differences is that in one you have an extra "app" key and no data in some of the other dictionaries. I would create a model where "app" is optional and then decode everything using that model. Once I had my data decoded I might convert (or filter) the content so I only kept what is interesting to me.